# Warn no Parameter ao subir a aplicação

Tags: demoiselle

Fiz uma aplicação usando o arquétipo Demoiselle 2.4.2 JSF+JPA com várias classes de visão que estendem da `AbstractEditPageBean`. Em algumas adicionei um parâmetro, como neste exemplo:

```
@ViewController
public class ContratoEstagioInstituicaoEditMB extends AbstractEditPageBean<...

@Inject
@ViewScoped
@Name("c")
private Parameter<String> contratoParametro;
```

Quando a aplicação sobe aparece o alerta no console:

```
6188 WARN  org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap - WELD-001440 Scope type @br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.annotation.ViewScoped() used on injection point [field] @Inject @Name @ViewScoped private br.com.teste.myApp.view.ContratoEstagioInstituicaoEditMB.contratoParametro
```

Devo me preocupar com isso? Estou fazendo algo errado?

Obrigado

Fernando

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente usa-se @ViewScoped no Managed Bean e não nos parâmetros do mesmo.

O alerta é justamente sobre isso.

Comment: Inicialmente eu coloquei sem o ViewScoped, mas o MB "perdia" o parâmetro ao usar o [Dialog Frameworkd do Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/data.xhtml). Aí notei que na [documentação do Parameter](http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/framework/reference/2.4.2/html/parametro.html) também usa.

Comment: O warn realmente é porque o ManagedBean já tem a anotação ViewControler que por sua vez é um estereótipo que também contem o ViewScoped e o CDI(weld) deveria aplicar o mesmo escopo para os atributos. Estranho que esteja "perdendo" o parâmetro. Mas se isso é o que resolve não há problemas, pois é só um warn.